# Criar pacote no Windows

Tags: r

Dado um conjunto de funções, como criar um pacote no OS Windows?

Por exemplo para as duas funções abaixo:

```
soma = function(x, y){
res = x + y
res
}

multiplica = function(x,y){
res = x*y
res
}
```

Comment: Você utiliza um editor de R? tipo Rgui?

Comment: Uso o apenas o Rstudio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No RStudio, clique em Project > New Project

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Em seguida clique em `New Directory`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Depois clique em `R Package`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Dê um nome ao pacote. Ele não pode conter espaços nem `-` além de outras regras.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O Rstudio irá abrir um projeto padrão com os seguintes arquivos:

- DESCRIPTION
- man/
- NAMESPACE
- R/

Entre na pasta R e crie quantos arquivos `.R` você quiser com as suas funções.

Clique em `Build & Reload`. Pronto o pacote foi criado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Claro que pacotes podem ser muito mais complicados do que isso. Recomendo a leitura [deste link](http://errar.how/introducao_devtools.html) que é uma breve introdução. Mas com certeza a melhor referência é o [livro do Hadley](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/). O @JulioTrecenti fez uma apresentação sobre a criação de pacotes também que está no [youtube](https://www.google.com.br/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj66svJjIzNAhVIHh4KHY68DDQQtwIIKTAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3D2CI8OvZPhqI&usg=AFQjCNGQDjZn7XSLfZN4x1X7_P7kunafrQ&sig2=ag1kTspvwH_PeVQdpjOvew).